# Create list of attributes in XML

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

I'm serializing an XML in C# and setting the root element to having one attribute as in:

```
XmlDocument xml = GetXMLDocument();
xml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("code", "1234");
```

But now there can be multiple codes associated with each XML e.g. code = "1234", code = "2345" etc.

How can I represent this in C# to achieve what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: This question should be removed from its C# context, as it seems to be entirely about Xml. Moreover, "the best way" may depend on the concrete use case, and possibly also on developers' preferences, so it might not be answerable. Rather, ask for "a way".

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the description. I've kept the C# tag as that's the code I'm implementing it in and there may be questions regarding what data types I should use to achieve this.

Comment: Hi , you can use the following explanation: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4639/customize-xml-serialization-using-ixmlserializable/ let me know if that helps you...

Comment: Thanks @DeJaVo, I think this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this in XML.  From the [XML specification Section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-attr): "Well-formedness constraint: Unique Att Spec: An attribute name MUST NOT appear more than once in the same start-tag or empty-element tag.".  You need to make those codes be nested elements instead.